# Testing the impact of a events on time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, causality, intervention-analysis

**Context**

I'm working with product data for a retail company. I have the daily impressions (number of times it was viewed online) for all products over a 30 day period (can get more data).

Here is the data for one product:

on_sale = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True,
True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

impressions = [1,0,0,5,1,0,6,16,17,18,16,17,15,12,4,3,5,4,2,3,2,1,2,4,2,0,3,5,13,3]

So this product was on sale from index 7 to index 13.

[image]

We expect that when a product is on sale, it will see an increased number of impressions.

We have introduced a new piece of logic that identifies all on sale products and moves them up into a 'better' advertising campaign, with the aim of increasing their impressions over and above what the normal level of impressions for that on sale product would be.

**Question**

What is the best way to test the impact of this new piece of logic?
In particular, how can I test the impact of moving on sale products into a better campaign (in terms of impressions) relative to what we'd expect for the same on sale products without moving them up a campaign?

I imagine some sort of A/B test where I randomly take some of the on sale products and apply the new logic to them (i.e. move the products up) and compare the change in impressions to a control group of on sale products that I don't apply the new logic to.

Any insight into this problem would be great. I am looking for test that can be implemented in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Google's [CausalImpact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html) method  might be useful (python implementation [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycausalimpact/)). Briefly, you use pre-sale data to train a model that forecasts impressions, then forecast them for the sales period, and estimate the sales effect as a difference between observed and predicted impressions. CausalImpact uses a specific bayesian model to produce forecasts which is useful to estimate uncertainty, but in general this idea could be used with any (good enough) model.

Comment: Thanks! This looks very helpful. Just a note for anyone else that comes across this question - the original package has been deleted [source](https://willian-fuks.medium.com/hi-nick-cool-article-70c64a1bc610), but there is a new package being maintained [here](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact)